# Is there a tag field type in Keystone JS?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I'm looking for a tag field type which will autocomplete if the tag already exists, or simply add the tag if it doesn't. I think there are a lot of implementations of this in other CMS' and I wanted to shake the tree to see if someone had already done this before I roll up my sleeves. Assuming it existed, I imagine it would be implemented as follows:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Verbiage = new keystone.List('Verbiage', {
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
    map: { name: 'title' },
    defaultSort: '-createdAt',
    label: "Verbiage",
    plural : "Verbiage"
});

Verbiage.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
    tagged: { type: Types.Tag, required: false, many: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    publishedAt: Date
});

Verbiage.register();
```

Comment: Doesn't exist. But would be a fine addition. I'd wait till 0.4 lands. This fieldtype would require db access and probably full-text search through the existing tag names.

Comment: @HarryMoreno - I'll take your suggestion to wait for 0.4 and try to roll this. Thanks for the tip..

Comment: Any plans to add this feature?